# Cannot open orientdb database in the console when it is created programatically in Java

Tags: java, orientdb

I created a new graph database in Java using the "normal" code

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/home/miguel/orientdb-community-2.1.4/databases/flora","admin","admin");
final OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
```

it gets created, and everything works ok in the Java app.

However, I cannot open this database from the console nor the studio. The server gives me the error:

```
connect remote:localhost/flora admin admin    
Connecting to database [remote:localhost/flora] with user 'admin'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: 
Cannot open local storage '/home/miguel/orientdb-community-2.1.4/databases/flora' with mode=rw
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted.
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
```

If I add the following line in the storages of orientdb-server-config.xml

```
<storage name="flora" path="plocal:/var/orientdb/databases/flora" userName="admin" userPassword="admin" loaded-at-startup="true" />
```

the DB opens but seems to be empty (although it's not empty when accessed from Java).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that I was using version 2.2.0 in Java, and version 2.1.4 in the server; the database files were not compatible.
It worked as soon as I downgraded to 2.1.4 in Java.